# Lat,Lon to pixel coordinates in image

Tags: android, latitude-longitude, google-latitude

Hi I am new to android development.

I am on college project its based on location which is need to convert lat/lng to pixel coordinates.
Here i added example image to find excate x,y for marked point here link(https://i.stack.imgur.com/anTGh.png).
Given data is 4 lat/lng points for corners of image

Answer (score 0):

**when you click on the map to certain point the map object returns the lat/lon along with pixels**

you can try this...

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e){
console.log(e)
});
```

you will find pixels object into that

Comment: i am not using map. its only static image